# Filtering schema out of NSwag swagger

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, nswag

I have an ASP.NET full framework application with API endpoints. I am using NSwag to generate a swagger document. This all works.

I need to generate a document for only a small subset of the endpoints. The paths are filtered, but the schema is not. How do I filter the schema objects to match the path filtering?

Example:
I have this filter

```cs
    public class IncludeControllersInSwagger : IOperationProcessor
    {
        public Task<bool> ProcessAsync(OperationProcessorContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(
                context.ControllerType == typeof(ControllerA));
        }
    }
```

And this at startup:
`settings.GeneratorSettings.OperationProcessors.Add(new IncludeControllersInSwagger());`

The controllers are:

```cs
    public class AResponse
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public bool Flag { get; set; }
    }

    public class BResponse
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    [Route("a")]
    public class ControllerA : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public AResponse Get()
        {
            return new AResponse
            {
                Message = "Hello from A",
                Flag = true
            };
        }
    }

    [Route("b")]
    public class ControllerB : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public BResponse Get()
        {
            return new BResponse
            {
                Message = "Hello from B",
                Count = 42
            };
        }
    }
```

Then the generated swagger contains just one path:

```
  "paths": {
    "/a": {
      "get": {  .. etc
    }
  }
```

And that's all, this is correct.

**But** the schemas contains both:

```
 "schemas": {
      "AResponse": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
 etc
      },
      "BResponse": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
etc
        }
      }
    }
```

**The `BResponse` type should not be there.** How do you remove it?

This extra data makes the Schemas section extremely verbose and unsuitable for public documentation in the case where there are over 10 endpoints, and only 2 are exposed via a gateway and therefor documented in swagger.

There is a `ISchemaProcessor` but it does not return a Boolean like the `IOperationProcessor`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried to add the operation filter as first element?

i.e. `OperationProcessors.Insert(0, new IncludeControllersInSwagger())`

I think this is important as it will filter out the operation before the dto schemas are generated and added to the document.

Comment: Updated wiki: https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/wiki/Document-Processors-and-Operation-Processors

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer to your problem, as you already got an answer that seems to work. I do have a suggestion however. Instead of checking the type of controller in your processor, I would suggest to create a custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class IncludeInSwaggerAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Then change your processor to look for this attribute:

```
public class IncludeInSwaggerOperationProcessor : IOperationProcessor
{
    public async Task<bool> ProcessAsync(OperationProcessorContext context)
    {
        return context.ControllerType.GetCustomAttributes<IncludeInSwaggerAttribute>().Any() || 
               context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<IncludeInSwaggerAttribute>().Any();
    }
}
```

This way, you can add the attribute to any new controller you want to include in swagger without having to change your processor. You can also add the attribute on a single action to only include that action, leaving the rest of the actions in the controller out of swagger.